# Does Actionscript have a math specification?

Tags: actionscript-3, floating-point, specifications, deterministic

[This Flash game](http://fantasticcontraption.com/original/) has a lot of players including me and some friends. We noticed the same thing can run differently for different people. The math in the simulation is definitely to blame. Whether the cause is in hardware, OS, browser, 32-bit/64-bit, etc. is not really known. But with the combinations we have to test with, we've gotten 5 distinct end results from the same simulation starting conditions, and can likely get more.

This makes me wonder, **does Actionscript have a floating point math specification?** If so, what does it say about the accuracy and determinism of the computations?

I compare to Java, which differentiates between regular floating point math with the `Math` class and deterministic floating point with the `StrictMath` class and `strictfp` keyword. Both are always within 1 ulp of the exact result, this also implies the regular math and strict math always give results within 1 ulp of each other for a single operation or function call. The docs are very clear about this. I'd expect other respectable languages to have something similar, saying how accurate their floating point computations are and if they give the same results everywhere.

---

Update since some people have been saying the game is dishonest:

Some others have taken apart the swf and even made mods for it, they've seen the game engine and can confirm there is no randomness. Box2d is used for its physics. If a design ever does run differently on subsequent runs, it has actually changed due to some bug, usually this is a visible difference, but if not, you can check the raw data with [this tool](http://id36.ueuo.com/rd.php) and see it is different. Different starting conditions as expected get different end results.

As for what we know so far, this is results on a test level:

[image: Large table showing 5 different results for various users.]

For example, if I am running 32-bit Chrome on my desktop (AMD A10-5700 as CPU), I will always get that result of "946 ticks". But if I run on Firefox or Internet Explorer instead I always get the result of "794 ticks".

Comment: It's possible that the game is dishonest in a slightest, probably adding something random to its simulations. Also it's possible that the simulations were not exact, unless there is a save/load transfer that does store all objects with required precision (whatever coordinates are used in the game). There is really not enough data to say something about Flash math as is providing different results on different systems, while it can certainly happen should Flash use native calls to multiply floats, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Actionscript doesn't really have a math specification in that sense. This is the closest you'll get:

https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Math.html

It says at the bottom of the top section:

> The Math functions acos, asin, atan, atan2, cos, exp, log, pow, sin, and sqrt may result in slightly different values depending on the algorithms used by the CPU or operating system. Flash runtimes call on the CPU (or operating system if the CPU doesn't support floating point calculations) when performing the calculations for the listed functions, and results have shown slight variations depending upon the CPU or operating system in use.

So to answer our two questions:

What does it say about accuracy? Nothing, actually. At no point does it mention a limit to how inaccurate a result can be.

What does it say about determinism? Hardware and operating system are definitely factors, so it is platform-dependent. No confirmation for other factors.

If you want to look any deeper, you're on your own.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/learning/as3-fundamentals/data-types.html), Actionscript has a catch-all `Number` data type in addition to `int` and `uint` types:

> The Number data type uses the 64-bit double-precision format as specified by the IEEE Standard for Binary Floating-Point Arithmetic (IEEE-754). This standard dictates how floating-point numbers are stored using the 64 available bits. One bit is used to designate whether the number is positive or negative. Eleven bits are used for the exponent, which is stored as base 2. The remaining 52 bits are used to store the significand (also called mantissa), the number that is raised to the power indicated by the exponent.
>
> By using some of its bits to store an exponent, the Number data type can store floating-point numbers significantly larger than if it used all of its bits for the significand. For example, if the Number data type used all 64 bits to store the significand, it could store a number as large as 265 – 1. By using 11 bits to store an exponent, the Number data type can raise its significand to a power of 21023.
>
> Although this range of numbers is enormous, it comes at the cost of precision. Because the Number data type uses 52 bits to store the significand, numbers that require more than 52 bits for accurate representation, such as the fraction 1/3, are only approximations. If your application requires absolute precision with decimal numbers, use software that implements decimal floating-point arithmetic as opposed to binary floating-point arithmetic.

This could account for the varying results you're seeing.